# Error en Python: NameError name XXX is not defined

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en Python y estoy haciendo unos ejercicios de prueba, y estoy teniedo problemas en uno que me he inventado.

Quiero recoger nombres, meterlos en un vector, y ordenarlos. Esto lo había hecho antes con números, pero sin un `while` (preguntando con anterioridad cuántos números se iban a pedir ordenar para poder utilizar un `for`).

Ya os digo, será una chorrada, pero no consigo ver el error:

```
nombres = []

print("Introduce nombres y los devolvere ordenados. Escribe stop cuando quieras acabar")

stop = "stop"
while (input() != stop):

    nombres.append(input())

nombres.sort()

print(nombres)
```

Me devuelve este error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) en `python3x`es la forma adecuada de pedir un dato al usuario, sin embargo en `python2x` además de pedir una entrada de usuario, el interprete la evalúa tal como si fuera código Python, de ahí el error, se está evaluando la cadena `jaime` y el interprete justamente te está diciendo que tal nombre no está definido. En `python2x` deberías usar [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) o mudarte a la versión `3x`.

Por otro lado tienes un problema de concepto, estás pidiendo el ingreso de datos pero no siempre lo logras agregar a la lista, el `input()` del `while` es el que estaría mal. Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
nombres = []

print("Introduce nombres y los devolvere ordenados. Escribe stop cuando quieras acabar")

stop = "stop"
valor = raw_input()
while (valor != stop):
    nombres.append(valor)
    valor = raw_input()

nombres.sort()
print(nombres)
```

Answer (score 1):

El mayor problema es que tu bucle `for` verifica la `input` dos veces por bucle. Esto no es verificar la misma entrada dos veces, sino pedir dos entradas por ciclo.

```
nombres = []
stop = "stop"

# Valor inicial
current = input("Introduce nombres y los devolvere ordenados. Escribe stop cuando quieras acabar: ")

while (current != stop):
    nombres.append(current)
    current = input()

nombres.sort()
print(nombres)
```

Comment: Siempre es bueno indicar algún tipo de explicación a la hora de poner respuestas de código. (¡Qué bueno verte por aquí también!)

Comment: Dicho lo cual, también puedes hacer un `do while` diciendo `while True .... if current == stop: break`.

Comment: @fedorqui hola! Ya he puesto un poco de explicación :) y sí, tienes razón - pero quise conservar lo más posible de la lógica del código original.